# CounterPoint 8.3.9 and Cyrillic fonts

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, system, radiant

Guys,
does anybody ever try to print messages on your invoices using language other then English?

I am using Okidata matrix printers for invoicing and while Crystal prints everything perfectly fine as soon as same invoice comes out 
from CounterPoint 8.3.9 all Cyrillic fonts looks like bunch of ???????.

Anyone knows how to resolve this, if it is possible at all...

By the way to stop useless questions- yes I did print same report directly from Crystal to Okidata and it did look fine.
Is there a languages settings somewhere in CP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like none knows CounterPoint here.

That is what I found:

Radian does not support any other languages, at least not now. Therefor they did not put any other fonts settings and no other languages can be used on reports.

Here is a solution: insert picture of needed text into Crystal report in question. manipulating pictures in code is easy enough for decent programmer.